# $\sup_{x \ge 0} |x|^{1 + \varepsilon} \mathbb P[X \gt x] \lt \infty$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ implies $X$ integrable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with $\mathbb P[X \ge 0] = 1$. I want to show that $\sup_{x \ge 0} |x|^{1 + \varepsilon} \mathbb P[X \gt x] \lt \infty$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ implies that $X$ is integrable.

My attempt is to use that $\mathbb E[X] = \int_{[0,\infty)} \mathbb P[X>x] \lambda(dx)$ but I am not sure how to continue from that.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $|x|^{1 + \epsilon}.$  You'll get something bounded multiplied by something integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment of Dzoooks (thanks to Kavi Rama Murthy for the correction):

\begin{align}
E[|X|] = E[X] = \int_0^\infty P[X > x] \, dx
&\le 1 + \int_1^\infty (|x|^{1+\epsilon} P[X > x]) |x|^{-(1+\epsilon)} \, dx\\
&= 1 + c \int_1^\infty  |x|^{-(1+\epsilon)} \, dx < \infty
\end{align}

The first inequality is due to $\int_0^1 P[X>x] \, dx \le \int_0^1 \, dx$.

Comment: The integral on the right extreme is not convergent.

Comment: @Pazu use the argument of angryavian but split the integral over $(0,\infty)$ into the integrals over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$

Comment: Just to be sure: $c= \sup_{x \ge 0} |x|^{1 + \varepsilon} \mathbb P[X \gt x]$, right?